# updating subset of parameters in dynet

Tags: neural-network, nlp, dynet

Is there a way to update a subset of parameters in dynet? For instance in the following toy example, first update `h1`, then `h2`:

```
 model = ParameterCollection()
 h1 = model.add_parameters((hidden_units, dims))
 h2 = model.add_parameters((hidden_units, dims))
 ...
 for x in trainset:
    ...
    loss.scalar_value()
    loss.backward()
    trainer.update(h1)
    renew_cg()

 for x in trainset:
    ...
    loss.scalar_value()
    loss.backward()
    trainer.update(h2)
    renew_cg()
```

I know that [`update_subset` interface](http://dynet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python_ref.html#dynet.Trainer.update_subset) exists for this and works based on the given parameter indexes. But then it is not documented anywhere how we can get the parameter indexes in dynet Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution is to use the flag `update = False` when creating expressions for parameters (including lookup parameters):

```
import dynet as dy
import numpy as np

model = dy.Model()
pW = model.add_parameters((2, 4))
pb = model.add_parameters(2)
trainer = dy.SimpleSGDTrainer(model)

def step(update_b):
    dy.renew_cg()
    x = dy.inputTensor(np.ones(4))
    W = pW.expr()
    # update b?
    b = pb.expr(update = update_b)

    loss = dy.pickneglogsoftmax(W * x + b, 0)
    loss.backward()
    trainer.update()
    # dy.renew_cg()

print(pb.as_array())
print(pW.as_array())
step(True)
print(pb.as_array()) # b updated
print(pW.as_array())
step(False)     
print(pb.as_array()) # b not updated
print(pW.as_array())
```

- For `update_subset`, I would guess that the indices are the integers suffixed at the end of parameter names (`.name()`).
  [In the doc](http://dynet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/optimizers.html#_CPPv3N5dynet7Trainer6updateERKNSt6vectorIjEERKNSt6vectorIjEE), we are supposed to use a `get_index` function.
- Another option is: [`dy.nobackprop()`](http://dynet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python_ref.html#dynet.nobackprop) which prevents the gradient to propagate beyond a certain node in the graph.
- And yet another option is to zero the gradient of the parameter that do not need to be updated (`.scale_gradient(0)`).

These methods are equivalent to zeroing the gradient before the update. So, the parameter will still be updated if the optimizer uses its momentum from previous training steps (`MomentumSGDTrainer`, `AdamTrainer`, ...).

Comment: Hmm ... something weird is going on: If you change the order of the steps, to first be step(False), then step(True), it will give an error ...

Comment: It seems that using `.expr(update=False)` returns `None` before the first call to `dy.renew_cg()`. I moved the call to `dy.renew_cg()` at the beginning of the loop to solve this. I am not sure if it is a bug or not... I thought the first CG was initialized automatically.

Comment: I realized it does, so removed the comment :) - in the initial_state you can set update=True/False. See http://dynet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python_ref.html#dynet._RNNBuilder.initial_state